# Can someone help me understand class variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand class variables and how to change them, and I cannot understand why in this sample code, b is not changed to 9999.  I am trying to permanently change b so that any time Whatever.b is called, from anywhere else in the code, it will print 9999.

```
class Whatever():
    b = 5
    def __init__(self):
        Whatever.b = 9999

class test():
    print(Whatever.b)

Whatever()
test()
```

This outputs:

```
5
```

Comment: The print is executed during the definition of the `test` class. That is before `Whatever` is instantiated, so it is before the class attribute is set to 9999.

Comment: But I am calling Whatever() before calling test().... So how is my print statement executed early

Comment: `test()` isn't what causes the print. The print is called when the `class test` definition is executed.

Comment: No, that would be if you did `def test():`, but you did `class test():`. A typo perhaps?

Comment: I think that Whatever.b = 9999 should be b=9999 because it is inside the Whatever class.

Comment: @Nandostyle. Try it. See what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the print statement in `test` happens when the class is *defined*, not when it is instantiated. Because it happens when it is defined, it happens before the call to `Whatever()` and thus `b` hasn't been reset.

It's unusual to put executable code in a class but outside of any methods. Contrast the behavior of your code with the output you get when you define `Test` like this:

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        print(Whatever.b)
```

When I make the above change, the output shows that b is now 9999. That is because the print statement happens when you create the instance of `test` rather than when you define the class, and because you create the instance after you've created an instance of `Whatever`.

Answer (score 3):

The `test()` call is irrelevant.
The print is executed during the **definition** of the `test` class. That is before `Whatever` is instantiated, so it is before the class attribute is set to 9999.

```
class Whatever():
    b = 5
    def __init__(self):
        Whatever.b = 9999

class test():
    print(Whatever.b)
# Now the print happens (while Whatever.b is still 5)

Whatever()
# Now Whatever.b is 9999
test()
```

If you check the value of `Whatever.b` any point *after* you have instantiated `Whatever()`, you will find that the value has indeed been changed to 9999.

Comment: The comments are my attempt to explain why the code prints 5 instead of 9999. That is what the question asks for, no?

Comment: @Nandostyle: But (glossing over some details of the class creation process) the `b` in the `Whatever` class definition and `Whatever.b` *are* the same variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the line test() isn't the line that make the 5 print out.
I can run:

```
class Whatever():
    b = 5
    def __init__(self):
        Whatever.b = 9999

class test():
    print(Whatever.b)

Whatever()
```

and it will still output `5`, since the `print` statement is run during the definition of the class `test`.

Basically what your class `test` does is print `Whatever.b` without initializing class `Whatever` so `Whatever.b` never gets set to `9999`.

To get `9999` outputted you want to initialise `Whatever` first in the class definition, like this:

```
class Whatever():
    b = 5
    def __init__(self):
        Whatever.b = 9999

class test():
    Whatever()
    print(Whatever.b)

Whatever()
```

Comment: This does help, but it also raises another question for me. I do not see where test() is ever called, so how is the print statement ever even ran?

Comment: @Lzypenguin I am not absolutely sure about this, but the print statement gets run when you define the class test(). So print is executed right as the compiler handles the class definition.

Answer (score 1):

On the test() class you need to instantiate Whatever() like this:

```
    myWhatever = Whatever()
    print(myWhatever.b)
```

Then only run Test()

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3